# Javassist.CannotCompileException when trying to create method with String and Object array as input parameters

Tags: java, dynamic, dynamic-compilation, java-assist

I need to create a method using JavaAssist CtMethod.
This method need to accept a String and an array of objects as input parameters as below

```
String methodBody = "$1.look(\"" + (lname).replace("\"", "").trim() + "\"" + " ," + new Object[] { lp.get(0) }+ ")";
```

where `lp` is List

but when i create the method I get exception:

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] syntax error near "String" ,[Ljava.lang"
```

Any idea why this exception is thrown from javaassist?

I actually want to pass the entire `lp` object as parameter into the method, but in the above code,I was trying to see if JavaAssist will accept if I pass just one entry in the list like

```
new Object[] { lp.get(0) }
```

Any idea why this exception is thrown from javaassist?

Comment: You're not calling a method,just building a string, also the error seems to come near `String` word, what are the lines before ?

Comment: What is the content of `methodBody` after all the values are expanded?